# Javascript function (tag manager) - Add 7 days from today and format it

Tags: javascript, date, google-tag-manager

I'm new with Javascript and I would like to create a Google Tag Manager function to return the date of Today + 7 days and format the result in "YYYY-MM-DD",

The purpose is to use this variable in the Google Review script that requires a estimated delivery date.
Example :
"estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD",

I tried the following function that return "undefined"
As I'm really new to JS, I don't know how to fix this function to make it work in Google Tag Manager the way I need it to.

```
 var sevenDaysFromNow = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);
 function formatDate(sevenDaysFromNow) {

var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

return [year, month, day].join('-');

}
```

Comment: You can have a look at https://momentjs.com/, you can do some thing like `date.add(7, 'days')`

Comment: `var d = new Date(date)` - date is undefined ... the parameter name is `sevenDaysFromNow` ... try `var d = new Date(sevenDaysFromNow)`

Comment: @BhaskerYadav - don't recommend a library that is no longer maintained by its author

Comment: *sevenDaysFromNow* is not a Date, it's a [time value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range), i.e. milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a small issue in your function:

```js
var sevenDaysFromNow = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);

function formatDate(date) {

  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

console.log(formatDate(sevenDaysFromNow));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I tried to update this on my Google Tag Manager contener but i still have a bad output: 

string  :   'NaN-NaN-NaN' 

On my chrome console when I tried the code it returns "2020-11-13
undefined "  and on firefox console just "undefined"

Is the code pure JS because I know Tag Manager doesn"t accept use of libraries for example ? 

Regards